# Intellisense problems with node.js development with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Usually we're in a microsoft stack development but for the project purposes we need to develop in node.js in visual studio 2017.
There are some things we don't understand at all but are quite annoying.

We've installed node.js tools for Visual Studio 2017 but intellisense work for some things and doesn't for others.

2 main problems we're facing:

1. For example, for some node modules (router, express, etc...) intellisense works fine. For others (mongorito, for examlple, but its not mongorito specific, there are many others also) we don't get any intellisense nor we can navigate through its definitions ('go to definition').
2. For any file we open we get alot of TSxxx error messages. something like this:

[image: TS Errors]

Don't know if its important but with the same setup we had our team members to work on angular 2/4 projects (that use node modules, of course) and everything worked fine.

So, if anyone has a piece of advice we would highly appreciate it. And please explain it like for a complete idiots.

PS.
Don't know if its important, but i must say that solution builds, all tests are good and all runs as it should. Its IDE problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, for everyone having the problem i'll post the solution here.

Problem was in typescript version. Now, that comes with a few details.
In Visual studio pre 15.2 you can't have typescript versions switching. So, i first updated VS to 15.2.

After that, i've installed Typescript SDK with latest typescript (2.4.1. i think at the moment).

Then go to Tools > Options > TextEditor > Javascript/Typescript > Intellisense > Here choose typescript version from the drop down.

[I'll leave answer unaccepted for a bit for the case someone comes with a better solution]